# What is meant by 'Memristance'?

Tags: memristor

What exactly do authors mean when they say 'memristance' increases by changing certain parameters of an input waveform to a Memristor. Case in point in Strukov's paper it is mentioned that Memristance increases with decreasing frequency:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:** A Google search will show the following result of Memristance:

Memristance is a property of an electronic component. If charge flows in one direction through a circuit, the resistance of that component of the circuit will increase, and if charge flows in the opposite direction in the circuit, the resistance will decrease.

There are 2 problems with this definition:

- The i-v characteristic is a loop. So at a given Voltage there can be 2 Memristance values.
- The authors seem to indicate lower slope means lower Memristance, that makes Memristance same as Resistance i.e **R = V/I**

Comment: Red-green-blue are graphs for increasing frequency.  The red graph is "steeper", so the current is higher for the same voltage drop.  Therefore the resistance is lower than the green and blue curves.  In other words, the resistance increases when the frequency increases.

Answer (score 1):

So I did some simulations and found out this, Memristance is basically the quantification of the maximum change in resistance that can be **achieved** for a given Memrsitor. The **'achieved'** part is important since from the equations:

[image]

You can see that the charge and current can turn out to be imaginary if we choose a wrong **amplitude** and **omega** in case of a sinusoidal wave. To further verify the basis of authors claims that Memristance decreases with **omega** for a sinusoidal wave I have plotted 2 plots for **Resistance** vs **Time** where Time is in the x-axis:

- omega = 1000
- omega = 5000
- omega = 10000 for given fixed set of Memristor physical parameters and amplitude

[image]

[image]

[image]

As predicted by the authors you can clearly see Memristance decreases with increasing **omega**.